# GitLab CI: How to keep going a job that fails

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have this gitlab-ci job and I would like it to just ignore failures and keep going. Do you have a way of doing that? Note that `allow_fail: true` does not work because it will just ignore that the job have failed however I want that the job keep executing in spite of failing commands in the middle.

Comment: EDIT: If you wonder why I would like that it is because I run a populate stage that should add stuff to my deployed environment. If it fails to push some data, because network issues for instance, it is not a problem to just ignore it and keep on going. I also would like to have this sometimes to test pipeline. If you are here just to farm reputation please don't do it, it is bad practice and you know it.

Answer (score 1):

*palms up, serious look: "We don't do that here"*

The pipeline is supposed to work every time, and by design its commands cannot fail. You can however:

- change the commands logic and avoid failure
- split the commands in different jobs, using the `on_failure` parameter to manage workflow
- force the commands to have a clean exit code (ie: using `|| true` after the fallible command)

During debug I often use the third option after debug statement, or after commands that I'm not sure how will behave. The definitive version, however, is supposed to always work.

Comment: Hum I couldn't agree less. I belive this might be true for 99% of stages however mine is a populate one that is supposed to add useful data to a testing environment if the test succeds. Also this could help on tests for the pipeline, to simply bypass. A simple no, we don't have this functionality would be more of a clear answer.

Comment: I think the suggestion of "force the command to have a clean exit code" is a reasonable approach that could extend beyond debugging. You could also add a bash script to your repository that does what you want and returns with an exit code of 0. If you call that script from your job then it can deal with errors as it wants without disrupting the pipeline.